# Is there a simple trick to solve a minimization problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Consider the following minimization problem:
$$
\text{minimize} \quad
\frac{( a + b )^2}{y - x} 
+\frac{a^2}{x}
+\frac{b^2}{1 - y}
\quad
\text{in} \quad 0 < x < y < 1,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are fixed positive numbers. Note how the minimization requirement forces 1) $x$ and $y$ to stay away from each other, 2) $x$ to stay away from $0$ and 3) $y$ to stay away from $1$.

This problem is quite easy to solve directly by taking derivatives and such, but in view of some possible generalizations which are of interest for me, I wonder whether there is a **simple trick** to find the answer. A trick which involves as little computations as possible.

I know my question is a bit vague, but I'd appreciate any ideas. I'd also like to hear about different possible approaches to similar minimization problems.

Comment: Yes, use the weighted version of the [inequality between the harmonic mean and the arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) The conditions on the variables makes each summand non-negative. Note how the weighted sum of the reciprocals of the summands is $(a+b)^2\frac{y-x}{(a+b)^2}+a^2\frac{x}{a^2}+b^2\frac{1-y}{b^2}=1$.

Comment: Could you give an idea about the motivation for this expression ?

Comment: @owl, very nice approach!

Comment: @JeanMarie, hm... My own motivation comes from a certain high excursion problem for Gaussian processes. I do not know how to state it in the space of a comment :)

Comment: Hmm. The Wikipedia doesn't mention the weighted version. Well, you can find them in other places, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777754/discreet-weighted-mean-inequality). or in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05874.pdf), the very first inequality, Bergstrom inequality, which is just a weighted HM-AM inequality re-arranged, can be applied directly to your problem.